# Embedded SQL directly vs calling as an API

Tags: sql, database

> Most database applications require a host programming language to use
>   SQL to communicate with the database. A wide range of programming
>   languages can be used with SQL, from traditional languages such as
>   COBOL, FORTRAN, and Assembler to more modern languages such as C/C++,
>   Java, and Visual Basic. Your choice of host programming language can
>   impact the way you will have to code SQL. For example, **SQL is embedded
>   directly into a COBOL program**, whereas **a language like C requires an
>   API like ODBC to issue SQL statements**.

*source: Craig S.Mullins-Database Administration The Complete Guide to Practices and Procedures*

What is the difference between embedding SQL directly in the host programming language and calling as an API?

Comment: I think it is just a syntactic difference.  Is there special syntax in the language to support SQL?  Or, do you enclose SQL statements in strings and pass them into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Convenience, that's all.  What Mullin's comment leaves out is that COBOL language doesn't understand SQL statements so a preprocessor is used to strip them out of a program prior to compiling and replaces them with, you guessed it, API calls.  I believe preprocessors exist for C as well as other languages so I don't really see where he's coming from.